Laravel hasOne with two matching fields
I need to establish a hasOne relationship that matches two fields simultaneously.
Here's my users table:



ID
user
conc
name




1
JDoe
ABC
John Doe


2
JDoe
ZXC
John Doe



And here's my membership table:



ID
user
conc
role




1
JDoe
ZXC
admin



In order to use another component that requires the relationship in the membership model, I need to use two simultaneous criteria: user and conc. The expected result is:
$memb = Membership::find(1);
$memb->user; // This should return the user with ID 2, since it has the same 'user' and 'conc'

I've tried using ->ofMany, but it seems like I need a join more than a where, and I can't make it work.
Edit: There will never be two records in the users table with the same user and conc, hence the hasOne and not hasMany relationship.

why not add user_id to membership table?

how would that make a difference?

that way each membership can only link to one user
